# Not able to use XPATH to interactive with the text filed in my special case

Tags: selenium-webdriver, xpath

From the following picture, I am trying to clear the "Server Address" field, and to input a new value. but somehow, it keeps giving me timeout exception.
[image]

here is my general python code. Any alternative ways I may try ?

```
  try:
        target = "//label[contains(text(), 'Server address')]/following-sibling::input"
        WebDriverWait(self.driver, 30).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, target))).clear()
        WebDriverWait(self.driver, 30).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, target))).send_keys(var)
    except Exception as e:
        ....
```

Thanks for the help.

Jack

Comment: Is your XPath inside an //iframe HTML ancestor?

Comment: I can see the element is inside an iframe. You need to switch to iframe first in order to access the element inside the iframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that the XPath exists inside an `iframe`. There is a certain approach when handling iframes which your [can read here](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/interactions/frames/). But in simple terms it means: You need to switch to the iframe which is seen as a seperate window by Selenium.

1. Write an XPath for the ancestor `iframe` of the HTML element you try to interact
2. Use the Selenium documentation according to the right language you use
3. After succesfull switching to the `iframe`, you can now interact with the proper HTML element `//label[contains(text(), 'Server address')]/following-sibling::input`

Answer (score 1):

The element you are trying to access is inside an `iframe`. you need to switch to `iframe` first in order to access the element.

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "iframe#main")))
try:
   target = "//label[contains(text(), 'Server address')]/following-sibling::input"
   WebDriverWait(self.driver, 30).until(
            EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, target))).clear()
   WebDriverWait(self.driver, 30).until(
            EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, target))).send_keys(var)
except Exception as e:
```